# Map of pointer to member functions : cannot convert void (*) to void (Object::*)

Tags: c++

I've got an error while trying to add a function to a pointer to member function map.

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

class Server {
protected:
    typedef void (*ScriptFunction)(std::pair<std::string, std::string>);
    std::map<std::string, ScriptFunction> internalScriptMap;
    void checkUserLogin(std::pair<std::string, std::string> packet) {}
    void handleUserCommand(std::pair<std::string, std::string> packet) {}

public:
    void setupServerInternalCommands() {
        internalScriptMap["login"] = &Server::checkUserLogin;
        internalScriptMap["clientcmd"] = &Server::handleUserCommand;
    }
};
```

CodePad says (http://codepad.org/JZHeJSPz) :

```
t.cpp: In member function 'void Server::setupServerInternalCommands()':
Line 13: error: cannot convert 'void (Server::*)(std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)' to 'void (*)(std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)' in assignment
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I don't understand why my code doesn't want to compile, why does the compiler cannot convert 'void (*)' to 'void (Server::*)'.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use:-

```
typedef void (Server::*ScriptFunction)(std::pair<std::string, std::string>);
```

i.e pointer to member function instead of pointer to function.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are incompatible. Member function pointers and function pointers are different in terms of the standard.

Comment: Oh .. There isn't a way to have these functions inside my class then (i.e. they have to be outside) ?

Comment: @JambonPingouin I'd use `std::function` instead.

Comment: you may declare them static. Main difference between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member is that pointer to member has `this` reference.

Comment: @Raiv : I don't want to declare them as static, as I want to keep them inside my class and use non-static members, but good to know.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : ravi's answer suits me, but I'll ty to work around std::function, just in case.